# How can I get everything between multiple <title> tags

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get multiple titles between the title tags from this site:

http://drewgarcia23.3owl.com/LiveScores/mlb.php

I have tried the simplexml way. But that may be stupid since it is a php file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've also tried preg matching the tags and stripping the tags and get errors. Getting frustrated so I am posting this. 
Not good coding

```
$url = 'http://drewgarcia23.3owl.com/LiveScores/mlb.php';
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
$items = $rss->channel->item;
echo $items;
```

Comment: First, please `var_dump($rss);` and update the result in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`simplexml_load_file()` function interprets an XML file into an object.

It's a php file that generate xml. So:

```
$url = 'http://drewgarcia23.3owl.com/LiveScores/mlb.php';
$items = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($items->channel->item as $item) {
    echo $item->title . "<br>";
}
```

**Titles outputs successfully.**

```
NY Mets 5 Atlanta 2 (FINAL)
Minnesota 5 Houston 6 (FINAL)
Miami 7 Chicago Cubs 9 (FINAL)
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It had something to do with my server so I got tons of errors, but I used a different server and that code worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

`/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i`

`preg_match_all('/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i', '{{your data}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <title>MLB Scores</title>
            [1] => <title>MLB Scores</title>
            [2] => <title>NY Mets 5 Atlanta 2 (FINAL)</title>
            [3] => <title>Minnesota 5 Houston 6 (FINAL)</title>
            [4] => <title>Miami 7 Chicago Cubs 9 (FINAL)</title>
            [5] => <title>Texas 4 Oakland 11 (FINAL)</title>
            [6] => <title>Toronto 3 Arizona 4 (FINAL - 10 INNINGS)</title>
            [7] => <title>San Francisco 0 San Diego 2 (BOT 2ND)</title>
            [8] => <title>Detroit 0 Boston 0 (TOP 1ST)</title>
            [9] => <title>Baltimore 0 Cleveland 0 (BOT 1ST)</title>
            [10] => <title>Chicago Sox 1 NY Yankees 0 (TOP 1ST)</title>
            [11] => <title>Washington 1 Philadelphia 0 (TOP 1ST)</title>
            [12] => <title>St. Louis 0 Cincinnati 0 (BOT 1ST)</title>
            [13] => <title>Seattle at Kansas City (8:10 PM ET)</title>
            [14] => <title>Pittsburgh at Milwaukee (8:10 PM ET)</title>
            [15] => <title>LA Dodgers at Colorado (8:40 PM ET)</title>
            [16] => <title>Tampa Bay at LA Angels (10:00 PM ET)</title>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => MLB Scores
            [1] => MLB Scores
            [2] => NY Mets 5 Atlanta 2 (FINAL)
            [3] => Minnesota 5 Houston 6 (FINAL)
            [4] => Miami 7 Chicago Cubs 9 (FINAL)
            [5] => Texas 4 Oakland 11 (FINAL)
            [6] => Toronto 3 Arizona 4 (FINAL - 10 INNINGS)
            [7] => San Francisco 0 San Diego 2 (BOT 2ND)
            [8] => Detroit 0 Boston 0 (TOP 1ST)
            [9] => Baltimore 0 Cleveland 0 (BOT 1ST)
            [10] => Chicago Sox 1 NY Yankees 0 (TOP 1ST)
            [11] => Washington 1 Philadelphia 0 (TOP 1ST)
            [12] => St. Louis 0 Cincinnati 0 (BOT 1ST)
            [13] => Seattle at Kansas City (8:10 PM ET)
            [14] => Pittsburgh at Milwaukee (8:10 PM ET)
            [15] => LA Dodgers at Colorado (8:40 PM ET)
            [16] => Tampa Bay at LA Angels (10:00 PM ET)
        )

)
```